# Intuit Quickbooks API IPPDotNetDevKit library: Get a Bill entity with vendor name in a single call

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to get all QBO Bill entities with all their vendor names in a single call.

If I call `DataServices.FindAll()` I receive all the Bills with the correct VendorId, but the VendorName property is set to null.

Is there any way to retrieve the VendorName without making another service call?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.  You'll have to query for both Bills and Vendors.